# How to change an image in MS PowerPoint, when mouse over and out

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I need help to change an image when mousing over in PPT.
There are 3 answers on the slide. https://prnt.sc/tzulzc
When mousing over the image to choose the correct answer, I would like to the image change to another image, or just color change so that a user would know he/she can choose it. And then when mousing out again, it gets back to the previous image.
In that case of shape, not image, I could get help in the link below.
https://www.brightcarbon.com/blog/supercharging-powerpoint-interactive-presentations-with-vba-part-2/
But I couldn't get the accurate result since I applied it to the grouped shape.
I did try finding out something online and get nothing.
I hope someone gives me an idea.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

MouseOver events only fire once as the pointer moves from NotOverShape to OverShape (I'm making these terms up ... they're not constants or properties, other than conceptually).

The event won't fire when the mouse leaves the shape.

What you can do is add another (100% transparent) shape just behind the real shape you're working with and slightly larger. Now when the mouse moves into the real shape, it'll pass over the "bogus" shape and trigger a mouseover. Likewise, when the mouse moves OUT of the real shape, the same thing will happen.

A mouse-over macro attached to the bogus shape could toggle the value of a global boolean, say InBound. If InBound is true, do {whatever you need to} or if it's false, {undo whatever you've done}.